# Add up multiple numbers from the same class javascript

Tags: javascript

I know it might be a dumb question but I haven't find an answer 
I'm trying to sum 3 numbers from the same class but with no success

HTML

```
<p class = "box">1</p>
<p class = "box">2</p>
<p class = "box">3</p>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid black;

}
body {
  display: flex;
}
```

JS

```
var test = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

var sum = 0;
for(i=0; i < test.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(test[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're headed down the right track - currently, `text[i]` only returns the `HTMLElement` objects you've retrieved in your call to `document.getElementsByClassName()`. What you're looking for is to extract the `textContent` of the elements you're looping over:

```js
var test = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
var sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  sum += parseInt(test[i].textContent);
}
console.log(sum);
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<p class="box">1</p>
<p class="box">2</p>
<p class="box">3</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: I would change this `sum += parseInt(test[i].textContent);` to `sum += parseInt(test[i].textContent) | 0;`

Comment: What does | 0 at the end do ?

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close but what you are doing right now is trying to parse a whole p tag into a number and then add it which does not work. You can think of it like trying to do this:

```
sum += parseInt(<p class = "box">1</p>);
```

What you should do is get the contents of the tag by using tag.innerHTML like so

```
var sum = 0;
for(i=0; i < test.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(test[i].innerHTML);
}
```